# aravis camnode Frame error: ARV_BUFFER_STATUS_TIMEOUT

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am trying to run the aravis camnode but get an error message:
Frame error: ARV_BUFFER_STATUS_TIMEOUT

I ran the exact same node with same parameters yesterday, but now I can't get it working.

Here is the complete output I get when running camnode.

`eirik@ubuntu:~$ rosrun camera_aravis camnode`

"[ INFO] [1393242045.939900524]: Attached cameras:

"[ INFO] [1393242046.944975636]: # Interfaces: 2

"[ INFO] [1393242046.945041653]: # Devices: 1

"[ INFO] [1393242046.945078719]: Device0: Prosilica-02-2110A-06145

"[ INFO] [1393242046.946099931]: Opening: (any)

"[ INFO] [1393242047.043458478]: Opened: Prosilica-02-2110A-06145

"[ INFO] [1393242047.051520121]: Read parameter (string) AcquisitionMode: Continuous

"[ INFO] [1393242047.052089147]: Read parameter (string) ExposureAuto: Off

"[ INFO] [1393242047.052606205]: Read parameter (float) ExposureTimeAbs: 2000.000000

"[ INFO] [1393242047.053004840]: Read parameter (string) GainAuto: Off

"[ INFO] [1393242047.053854332]: Read parameter (string) TriggerMode: Off

"[ INFO] [1393242047.055533795]: Read parameter (string) TriggerSource: Line1

"[ INFO] [1393242047.080100210]: Camera does not support FocusPos.

"[ INFO] [1393242049.092995805]:     Using Camera Configuration:

"[ INFO] [1393242049.093051071]:     ---------------------------

"[ INFO] [1393242049.093407251]:     Vendor name          = Prosilica

"[ INFO] [1393242049.093876798]:     Model name           = GC650M (02-2110A)

"[ INFO] [1393242049.094351734]:     Device id            = 02-2110A-06145

"[ INFO] [1393242049.094386520]:     Sensor width         = 659

"[ INFO] [1393242049.094416641]:     Sensor height        = 493

"[ INFO] [1393242049.094447223]:     ROI x,y,w,h          = 0, 0, 659, 493

"[ INFO] [1393242049.094473899]:     Pixel format         = mono8

"[ INFO] [1393242049.094499654]:     BytesPerPixel        = 1

"[ INFO] [1393242049.094843820]:     Acquisition Mode     = Continuous

"[ INFO] [1393242049.095200192]:     Trigger Mode         = Off

"[ INFO] [1393242049.095552045]:     Trigger Source       = Line1

"[ INFO] [1393242049.095588934]:     Can set FrameRate:     True

"[ INFO] [1393242049.095950898]:     AcquisitionFrameRate = 89.5897 hz

"[ INFO] [1393242049.095984962]:     Can set Exposure:      True

"[ INFO] [1393242049.096014800]:     Can set ExposureAuto:  True

"[ INFO] [1393242049.096044887]:     Exposure             = 2000 us in range [8,6e+07]

"[ INFO] [1393242049.096074699]:     Can set Gain:          True

"[ INFO] [1393242049.096103940]:     Can set GainAuto:      True

"[ INFO] [1393242049.096133436]:     Gain                 = 1.000000 % in range [0.000000,22.000000]

"[ INFO] [1393242049.096163338]:     Can set FocusPos:      False

"[ INFO] [1393242049.096512460]:     Network mtu          = 8228

"[ INFO] [1393242049.096545200]:     ---------------------------

"[ WARN] [1393242049.593426990]: Frame error: ARV_BUFFER_STATUS_TIMEOUT

"[ WARN] [1393242049.616419706]: Frame error: ARV_BUFFER_STATUS_TIMEOUT

"[ WARN] [1393242049.616471828]: Frame error: ARV_BUFFER_STATUS_TIMEOUT

I did get some crash reports on an upgrade. I do not know if that is somehow connected with this problem. The error message for these three reports from package "ros-hydro-roscpp-traits 0.3.17-0precise-20140130-1927-+0000"

Error message: trying to overwrite /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_event which is also in package ros-hydro-roscpp 1.9.50-0precise-20131015-1959-+0000

Error message: trying to overwrite /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/header.h which is also in package ros-hydro-roscpp 1.9.50-0precise-20131015-1959-+0000

Error message: trying to overwrite /opt/ros/hydro/include/rosbag/buffer.h which is also in package ros-hydro-roscpp 1.9.50-0precise-20131015-1959-+0000

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem? Would be of big help. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132446/aravis-camnode-frame-error:-arv_buffer_status_timeout/) by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2014-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem seems to be that I had not configured my network card for jumbo frames.

After running

`ifconfig ethx mtu 9000`  it works

---

Originally posted by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) with karma: 108 on 2014-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benjamin.Nilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/20058/benjamin.nilson/) on 2015-11-19**:
Where there any other configurations that you had to change to fix this issue?